# Pythonnet not free memory after python script called

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, python.net

I use pythonnet to call python script in C#(.NET 6, API app), everytime after called, the memory just increased, never freed. For now, the only way to free memory is call ShutDown(), but the behavior is still confused.

For example, start my api app cost about 250M memory. Two ways to call ShutDown.

1. When I request the API action A(), after python script called, ShutDown() immediately, like this:

```
Action A()
    {
        var result = pyFunc.InvokeMethod("");
        PythonEngine.Shutdown();
        return result;
    }
```

The memory costs about 1.5G when execute python script, after ShutDown(), the memory still costs about 900M, not freed to 200+M.

2. When I request the API action A(), then I call action B() to ShutDown, action A does not ShutDown anymore, like this:

```
Action A(){
        var result = pyFunc.InvokeMethod("");
        return result;
    }

    Action B()
    {
        PythonEngine.Shutdown();
    }
```

The memory will be freed to 200+M.

Is anyone could tell me why? and is it ShutDown() the only way to free memory, this is strange, why the memory not freed after the script executed? I don't think it has called GC because my memory out source when I call the request many times(1.5G, 3G, 4.5G... increasing). Manually to dispose the PyObject does not work.

Did I missed something? Thanks in advance!

Best Regards!